# If $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ then does the inclusion $f^{-1}\big[Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]\big]\subseteq U$ hold for any $U\in\mathcal P(X)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Given a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ I am trying to prove or to disprove the inclusion
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}f^{-1}\big[Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]\big]\subseteq U
$$
where $U\in\mathcal P(X)$. So I observe that if $\eqref{1}$ did not hold then by the inclusion
$$
f\Big[f^{-1}\big[Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]\big]\Big]\subseteq Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]
$$
there would be exists $x\in X\setminus U$ such that $f(x)$ lies in $Y\setminus  f[X\setminus U]$ but obviously $f(x)$ lies even in $f[X\setminus U]$ so that we conclude $\eqref{1}$ must holds. I understand that this question could seem trivial but I need $\eqref{1}$ to prove another result and I decided to not put directely a question about that result because I want try to prove it by my self as exercise. So does $\eqref{1}$ holds? could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus f(X \setminus U))$. Then $f(x) \in Y \setminus f(X \setminus U)$, i.e. $f(x) \notin f(X \setminus U)$, so $x \notin X \setminus U$, i.e. $x \in U$, and that completes the proof.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for your check: question upvoted and once again time I will surely approve it when the site it lets do it... ;-)